# setting Back color of a disabled check box to white color

Tags: c#

Any one knows to make back color of a disables check box as white.
Now it is seeing as gray

Comment: You might want to specify what you use WPF? Winforms?

Comment: Users expect disabled checkboxes to look a certain way. Are you _sure_ you want to work against user expectations?

Comment: You really need to add more information to this question, or the community is very likely to close it. The only reason I didn't is because it seems @Keivan figured out what you were asking and provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could do that directly, what you could do as a work around would be to leave it enabled, change the back color, and ignore it's onclick event.

If it's something that will be common in your app, you could create your own custom checkbox control by inheriting from Checbox